# How to make text and background colour appear over just the image when hovering

Tags: css

I want an image to change colour (burgundy) when I hover over it, and show text at the same time (which relates to the image).  I want the text and background colour to appear neatly over just the image (just covering the image only), but instead I get too much of the screen covered in burgundy (as shown in image below). I have created a jsfiddle which shows the problem I have. The image also needs to be responsive, so when hovering, the 'hover' effect will always just cover the image.

https://jsfiddle.net/cardiffsteve/hnow7yxp/

```
<div id="Profile-Picture">
  <div class="colleague-image">
    <img width="200" height="200" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/">
  </div>
  <div class="colleague-text">
    <div class="colleague-name">Mr Big </div>
    <div class="colleague-job-title">The Boss </div>
    <div class="colleague-qualifications">Top Cat</div>
  </div>
</div>

#Profile-Picture {
  position: relative;
}

.colleague-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(142, 1, 60, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#Profile-Picture:hover .colleague-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `inline-block` to `#Profile-Picture`:

```css
#Profile-Picture {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This will make the `relative`ly positioned container to take the dimensions of its contents.

**Preview:**

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7cv536d/**

The other attempt is to make the text both vertically and horizontally aligned middle:

```css
#Profile-Picture {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.colleague-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(142, 1, 60, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.colleague-text .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  left: 0; right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#Profile-Picture:hover .colleague-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

img {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Profile-Picture">
  <div class="colleague-image">
    <img width="200" height="200" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats/">
  </div>
  <div class="colleague-text">
    <div class="center">
      <div class="colleague-name">Mr Big </div>
      <div class="colleague-job-title">The Boss </div>
      <div class="colleague-qualifications">Top Cat</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

I have used another `div` to scaffold for vertically centring.. `:)`

Comment: this is great, i need to change Top to zero and Left to zero, so the burgundy box covers the image properly. I notice there is a slight overlap at the bottom of the image, I wonder what causes that?

Comment: @CardiffSteve Are you expecting the one like the second snippet?

Comment: i had a fix below thanks from @przemek, it needs a line height adjustment. No idea why but it works . I have this working perfectly now https://jsfiddle.net/cardiffsteve/4vLhsbxk/1/

Comment: @CardiffSteve What's the specific adjustment? I had already given `line-height` if you see! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
#Profile-Picture {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.colleague-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(142, 1, 60, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Edit: Set top and left to 0, and add **display: inline-block;** to #Profile-Picture.

Result:
[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NTG0.png)

Comment: What if the images were dynamically sized?

Comment: In this case the width of the image is set inline to be 200px. Setting display: inline-block; on #Profile-Picture will work without setting a width on .colleague-text though.

Comment: thanks, almost there, how do i get the text nicely centred so its in the middle of the burgundy box on hover?

Comment: sorry, I can just use padding I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `display: table;` to `#Profile-Picture` will make it as your expected.

Give `transition:.6s all;` to make hover effect nice.

And it works perfect if image is responsive Or it's size change.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnow7yxp/3/)**

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes. seriously.

Comment: @PraveenKumar any reason?

Comment: Table - Use only for tabular data not for layout purposes.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i hear it first time. You should read it up first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: Sorry, but check these: [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html), [Table Layouts vs. Div Layouts: From Hell to… Hell?](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/)

Comment: @PraveenKumar i think that is for table layout v/s div not `display:table` it just make display like tabular.

Comment: Both `display: table` and it's `table-*` and `<table>` are same buddy. General good thing is to avoid it. I am saying it from my experience of over five years. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah and it's working fine there also. no any issue

Comment: Ha ha. LoL. Okay. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Move  **id="Profile-Picture"** to the image tag.

Comment: This doesn't work. `:(` Did you check your answer before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Give your `div` with id `Profile-Picture` style `display: inline-block`.

```css
#Profile-Picture {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.colleague-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(142, 1, 60, 0.72);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#Profile-Picture:hover .colleague-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="Profile-Picture">
  <div class="colleague-image">
    <img width="200" height="200" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/cats/">
  </div>
  <div class="colleague-text">
    <div class="colleague-name">Mr Big</div>
    <div class="colleague-job-title">The Boss</div>
    <div class="colleague-qualifications">Top Cat</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason why your burgundy color overlays more than just the image, is because `Profile-Picture` takes entire document width, as it has `display: block` by default.

---

There is still a small problem at the bottom, though. Add these rules to fix it:

```
#Profile-Picture {
  line-height: 0;
}
.colleague-text {
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

The reason is that your burgundy color will overlay `div` with id `Profile-Picture`, which is a bit bigger than the the image due to the fact that it also contains whitespaces and not just the image.

**Preview after fixes:**

[image]